# Why is counting the omer not in all haggadot?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, sefirat-ha-omer

We count the first day of the omer on the night of the second seder, yet some prominent, traditional haggadot do not include the bracha for counting (e.g., ArtScroll, Koren, Steinsaltz). Why not?

Comment: Many Haggadot also don't include Shema, which is said on _both_ Seder nights. Why not?

Comment: Do Artscroll and Koren count as “traditional”? The reason, I assume, is because not everyone counts at the Seder.

Comment: Israelis don’t have a second seder to count at, probably why some suddurim don’t have the b’racha .

Answer (score 4):

1 - Many people count in Shul right after Maariv. Although there are opinions that it is proper to say it at the end of the Seder (not to have two conflicting things - Seder / Omer) as far as I know the majority of people say it right after Maariv.

2 - Those living in Israel do not have a Seder where they say Omer at.

Comment: What do you mean by "(not to have two conflicting things - Seder / Omer)"?

Comment: It is called in Hebrew תרתי דסתרי, meaning a contradiction. If you say the Omer, then it must not be the first night of Pesach and why are you having a Seder? If you are having a Seder, then it must not be the time for Omer yet? Thus by saying it after the Seder there is less of a conflict.

Comment: Oh. From what you just wrote, it seems your parenthetical comment has to do with the reason we celebrate two days for a one day hag.  So, if we count the omer at shul and then go home and do the second seder then we are being inconsistent, in some way.

Comment: Gershon Gold do you have a source that counting before seder is a תרתי דסתרי ?