# Must maariv be said before the seder?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

One who says maariv at shul surely says maariv before the seder.  If one davens at home, must maariv be said before the seder? (This question came up in a comment to [Why is counting the omer not in all haggadot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102022/why-is-counting-the-omer-not-in-all-haggadot?noredirect=1#comment341510_102022).)

Comment: Do you have some reason to think this is different from any other Friday night? (I don't.)

Comment: @YehudaW AFAIK there’s no strict requirement to daven before the Friday night meal; it’s just something people do.

Comment: There may be some concern with Kri'at Shema moreso than the rest of Ma'ariv. IIRC, Tal. Berachot mentions that while Shema may be said all night, it is preferable to say it before *chatzot* lest one say, "I'll eat a little, sleep a little and say *Shema later." With a long Seder, I think there is a fairly high risk that of one were to start Seder first, he may forget to say *Shema*.

Comment: @DanF indeed as with every night of the year, if you want to eat dinner before Shema you need to appoint a guard to remind you after.

Comment: @DonielF- it's a *bit* more than just something people do- we need to say kiddush before Friday night dinner and l'hachtila you don't daven after drinking even a revit of wine